# Making an existing datagrid column into a hyperlink column

Tags: c#, datagrid

I am databinding a datagrid to a datasource and the data is coming through fine. Is there a quick way to make one of those columns into a hyperlink column?

Or do I need to create a hyperlink column that uses the same datatext field, then hide the original non-hyperlink column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use an action 'onclick' on the cell you want to be a hyperlink